# how to add column for edit/delete using ephemer:reactive-datatables package in meteor app

Tags: meteor

I am using ephemer:reactive-datatables in my meteor app for search,sort & paging. I want to do edit & delete functionality for data, so how can add column for edit & delete records & how will I pass id to these add/edit link.

Answer (score 0):

Please [read the original documentation](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple) it has plenty of examples there. Here is how you can create an action toolbar for instance for New,Edit,Delete of a record.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Tfrtip",
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    columns: [
        { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
            // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
            return data.first_name+' '+data.last_name;
        } },
        { data: "position" },
        { data: "office" },
        { data: "extn" },
        { data: "start_date" },
        { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
    ],
    tableTools: {
        sRowSelect: "os",
        aButtons: [
            { sExtends: "editor_create", editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_edit",   editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    }
} );
```